# Boolean checking in python

Tags: python-3.6

I have a function as below which return boolean value:

```
def is_new_records(conn, value):
    """
    Check if value already exists
    """
    with conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            query = """
            select not exists (select * from table
            where value = '{value}')
            """.format(value=value)
            cursor.execute(query)
            exists = cursor.fetchone()
            return exists
```

The function would return true/false wether value is exists in db or not. Now thats how I call this function:

```
if is_new_records(connection, value):

        # do something
else:
        # do seomthing else
```

Now when it returns true it executes code block in if but even it returns false it executes code block in if. My assumption is. that if condition is checking if the value returned is **not None**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function was returning tuple and not a boolean value:

```
def is_new_records(conn, value):
    """
    Check if value already exists
    """
    with conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            query = """
            select not exists (select * from table
            where value = '{value}')
            """.format(value=value)
            cursor.execute(query)
            exists = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            return exists
```

This change got it working